# R - extracting column in dataframes of a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, read.csv

I need to save a list of csv files and extract values from thr 13th row on of a specific column (the second one) from each of dataframes.

Here's my try:

```
temp <- list.files(FILEPATH, pattern="*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(temp)){ 
  assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i], header=TRUE, ski[=13, na.strings=c("", "NA")))
  subset(temp[i], select=2) #extract the second column of the dataframe
  temp[i] <- na.omit(temp[i])
```

However, this doesn't work. On the one hand, I think that's because of the `skip` argument of the `read.csv` command, as it apparently ignores the headers. On the other hand, if `skip` is not used, the following error pops up:

> Error in subset.default(temp[i], select = 2) :    argument "subset" is
>   missing, with no default

When I insert the argument `subset=TRUE` in the `subset` command, it doesn't give any error, but no extraction is performed.

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the files it's not easy to tell, but I would use `lapply`, not a `for` loop. Maybe you can get inspiration from something like the follwing. I use `read.table` because you `skip = 13` lines and `read.csv` reads in the first line as column headers. Note that I avoid the use of `assign`.

```
df_list <- lapply(temp, read.table, sep = ",", skip = 13, na.strings = c("", "NA"))
names(df_list) <- temp
col2_list <- lapply(df_list, `[[`, 2)
col2_list <- lapply(col2_list, na.omit)
names(col2_list) <- temp
col2_list
```

If you want `col2_list` to be a list of df's with just one column each, column 2 of the original files, then, like I've said in comment use

```
col2_list <- lapply(df_list, `[`, 2)
```

And to rename that one column and renumber the rows consecutively

```
new_name <- "the_column_of_choice"  #  change this!
col2_list <- lapply(col2_list, function(x){
            names(x) <- new_name
            row.names(x) <- NULL
            x
        })
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about just avoid the loop, however I think I do need a `for` loop as I'll need to further operate on each data frame.

Comment: @RobertP. But you can do that later, can't you? The type of problem you've described is better solved without explicit loops/assign. That's what I've tried to do. I especially always try to avoid `assign`.

Comment: @RobertP. In my answer I had forgotten the column separator that `read.csv` uses. So I've edited my code to include argument `sep = ","`.

Comment: no worries, I was using `read.csv` anyway. quick question - I am testing your solution, but I can't figure out how to rename the one column left, and how to set the row names as incremental numbers...

Comment: @RobertP. In `lapply(df_list, `[[`, 2)` try using just one `[`. The former will extract vectors, the latter sub-data.frames.If I understand it, I'll need to edit my answer again. Just a moment, please.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, @RobertP did Rui's solution work for you?